# What is a design of iChat?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, design-patterns, oop

iChat does not allow to change your credentials to your account when List window is open and you are connected to server. I am just wondering how this is implemented.

I could imagine that internally iChat has some sort of `ICAppDelegate` that hold a pointer to `ICPreferencesControler` and an array of `ICListWIndows`. And now how preferences are informed that list window is connected to something?

Is iChat using here `NSNotificationCenter`? Or maybe pointer to preferences window is passed with `-initWithPreferences:` to list window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to guess, I'd say it's more like an ICChatAccount object being passed around with something similar to -[ICChatAccount isConnected]. ICChatAccount would be saved to the preferences, but it would do more than just save and load preferences.